# Test for closing tags

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How do I test if the closing tags are available:

e.g.

```
<A>
  <n>  

  <r>
  </r>

<b>
</b>
```

In the above case I'm missing the `</A>` and `</n>` closing tags.
How do I check for this ?

**CODE:**

```
   try
            {
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.LoadXml(FileName);

            }
            catch (XmlException xe)
            {
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.LoadXml(FileName);
                xdoc.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("/n"));
                xdoc.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("/A"));
            }
```

But it's giving me an exception : data at the root is invalid. The xml is missing the closing tags for /n and /A. Please advise.

**EDIT 2:**

```
try
            {
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.LoadXml(FileName);
                                }
            catch (XmlException xe)
            {
               using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(FileName))
           {
               w.WriteLine("</n>");
               w.WriteLine("</A>");
           }
            }
```

Now with Edit 2, it goes and corrects the filename with the missing tags. But what if the xml already has available it still goes in and put's in another tag /n /A and gives me exception: unexpected end tag.

Comment: Are you loading an XMl file or creating and XMl file??

Comment: @Oedum: I'm loading an already existing xml file

Comment: Do you want to tell that the file is misisng the specific tags or just that it cannot load the xml file??

Comment: @Shaharyar: I have no clue how to test this, so added it as a question here

Comment: @Oedum: I will test what closing tags are missing and then add those closing tags using streamwriter/appendtext

Comment: Are you using this for html? Then http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ could help you along the way.

Comment: no after testing this and putting in the closing tags (which I need help for) I would be applying xsl to it and copying it to the destination using c#. HTML is not my concern here

Comment: Regarding your edited in code. If the `.LoadXML(FileName);` failed the first time (that's why you're in the `catch`) why shouldn't it fail the second time? What you have to do is, having caught the error, edit the file yourself without parsing it as XML so that you can parse it as XML once its been fixed by you.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Yes I have modified my code it works for files that are missing the tags. But what if I get a file that is already complete. It adds /n /A end of it (so we have it twice). and then it gives an exception: Unexpected end tag

Comment: Are you sure the file is now correct? Because you're adding the tags in the catch part, it should only do that if there's a problem. If the file is fine it would never get to that part. Obviously going forwards you will have to deal with other reasons why the file is invalid - you won't be able to just add `</n></a>` every time.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Yes even if there is a valid xml file, i tried reading the xe exception for catch on the console it says: Data at the root level is incorrect. But the oxygen isn't giving me any error on the xml file. I wonder whats wrong with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load it in an XmlDocument, Put a try-catch around it, if there is any exception it means there's something wrong with your XML string (Missing closing tags, invalid characters etc) -

```
try{
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
}
catch (XmlException xe)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(xe.Message);
}
```

Comment: But I need to check what tags are missing and then add those tags to fix the xml for further processing. Normally I find the 'A', 'n' tags missing

Comment: If you try the code I've posted, you'll see that it'll return the exception message as 
'Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: n, A. Line 7, position 5.'
What you do with that is upto you, this is I believe the simplest way of validating XML

Comment: Looks good, then how do I access n for example and close it in the catch

Comment: That logic has to be determined by you. Depending on whether <r> is a subelement of <n> or <n> has no subelements etc. If <n> has no elements, then look for the position of '<n>' and insert '</n>' after that position

Comment: That makes sense, can you demonstrate that with A being the root

Comment: I think I've more than answered your question, rest of the effort is upto you. Just a hint, If you know the root node, and it's not closed, then add the closing tag at the end of the XML string, for other nodes you can follow what I mentioned above.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the code (see my modified post for the code I used above) it is giving me an exception